# Copy data from postgres to db2

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to copy data from postgres to db2. Just a full table.

I found [these](http://www.paulsprogrammingnotes.com/2014/01/clonecopy-table-schema-from-one.html) instructions and am following them, but they're failing for me on the db2 side.

currently I'm doing:

```
engine_pstgrs._metadata = MetaData(bind=engine_pstgrs)
engine_pstgrs._metadata.reflect(engine_pstgrs)
table_one = Table('table_one', engine_pstgrs._metadata, schema='prod_schema')
print("Got prod_schema.table_one")
#Create new table
engine_db2._metadata = MetaData(bind=engine_db2)
new_pages = Table('new_pages', engine_db2._metadata, schema='mru')
print("Created new table")
for column in table_one.columns:
    print("Column appended to new table")
    new_pages.append_column(column.copy())
new_pages.create()
```

And I'm getting the error:
`(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following "TABLE MRU.new_pages (".  Expected tokens may include:  "<table_element_list>".  SQLSTATE=42601 SQLCODE=-104 [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE mru.new_pages (\n)\n\n']`

I'm open to trying another way (i.e. Pandas) but I'm not seeing how to do so in a sustainable amount of time (the table is very very large)

Comment: Surely you meant `for column in table_one.columns` instead of `new_pages.columns`?

Comment: @univerio yes! true. Just a typo in moving from my actual code to SO. I've edited the question

Comment: The error message implies that you attempt to create a table with no columns: `CREATE TABLE mru.new_pages (\n)`, which means that your `append_column()` calls fail or do not get executed. Debug your code.